# Displaying images through series of button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a website with a very basic functionality. Essentially the website is supposed to contain various buttons and display images based on which series of buttons are clicked. Unfortunately my experience in web development is limited (to non-existent), but I've found some code that works to some extent here on stackoverflow. Building on that, I wanted to alter the code in a way that allows me to achieve the functionality I desire.

Here's how the website is supposed to look like:

[image: supposed to look like this]

As you can notice, the website contains various buttons from A-D and 0-9. The button clicks are logged in the field beneath and once a combination has been put in that matches the name of a file, the image will be displayed.

Here's the code:

```js
              
    $(document).ready(function() {
      /**
       * Select the buttons.
       * The $display and $clickedButtons are just to output
       * the values that are stored.
       */
      const $buttons = $('.button');
      const $display = $('#display');
      const $clickedButtons = $('#clicked-buttons');
      const $reset = $('#reset');
      $reset.on('click', function() {
        values = [];
        $clickedButtons.text(values);
      });
      
      /**
       * Array which tracks your clicked buttons.
       * If a button is clicked, the value of that button
       * should be added to this array. The combination
       * of the values will then later represent the key.
       */
      var values = [];
      
      /**
       * Listen for the click event on all the buttons.
       * When clicked, get the value of that clicked button
       * and add that to the values array.
       * After that the clicked button values will be combined
       * to form a single key and check if that key matches 
       * a combination. If there is a match the content should
       * be anything other than undefined.
       */

      $buttons.on('click', function() {
        // This is the currently clicked button.
        const $button = $(this);
        
        // Get the value of the button.
        const value = $button.val();
        
        // If there already are 15 previously clicked buttons,
        // then empty the array, so we can start a new combination.
        if (values.length === 15) {
          values = [];
        }
        
        // Now add the newly clicked value.
        values.push(value);
        
        // This will output the current values in the array.
        $clickedButtons.text(values);
        
        // Transform the array into a single string.
        // This will be the key to select content.
        // ["1", "2", "3"] becomes "123".
        const key = values.join('');    
        
        // Check if key has a match in the combinations object.
        $display.attr('src', 'output/' + key + '.png');
      });
    });
```

Now to my problem: The code requires that they combination of buttons is clicked exactly in the order of the name of the image. So for example, inputting A-B-C-1-2-3 will display ABC123.png. For my purpose however, I would need the code to display ABC123.png even if the inputs are 31B2AC or any other combination of these 6 inputs. I've looked into the option of 'sorting' but this creates a problem on the other hand, namely that some of the pictures are named like this e.g. D9B6C4.png so there is no applicable logic like alphabetic or numerical that would be required for a sorting algorithm to function. Every image in the folder has an unique however so when ABC123.png exists, BCA321 cannot.

What I would need the script to do is to parse through the pictures and find the unique picture that contains all letters & numbers that are entered regardless of their order. Is that even possible? How would I go about achieving this?

///////// EDIT ////////

My attempt to add a display, a tracker of clicked buttons and as well as a remove button:

So not really sure why literally nothing is working. Neither the inputs are displayed in the appropriate field nor is a picture being displayed ...

```js
       
  const $buttons = $('.button');
  const $display = $('#display');
  const $clickedButtons = $('#clicked-buttons');
  const $removeButton = $('#remove-button');    
  const values = [];
        
var imgs = ["ABC123.png", "1A2B4C.png", "ABC132.png", "123ABC.png"];

function case_insensitive_comp(strA, strB) {
  return strA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(strB.toLowerCase());
}

function reSortFiles() {
  var all = {};
  imgs.forEach(function(a) {
    d = a.split(".");
    img = d[0].split("");
    img = sortStr(img);
    img = img.join("");

    all[img] ? all[img].push(a) : all[img] = [a];
  });

  return all;
}

function sortStr(str) {
  return str.sort(case_insensitive_comp)
}

function tryCombination() {
    // This will output the current values from the array.
    $clickedButtons.text(values);        
    
const key = values.join('');  
        
allImages = reSortFiles()
console.log(allImages)


buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")

clicked = "";

buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    clicked += e.target.dataset.value;
    clicked_s = sortStr(clicked.split("")).join("")
    console.log(clicked, clicked_s)
    img = allImages[clicked_s]
    if (img) {
      console.log("Found: ", img.join(","))
      clicked=""; 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
   
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.buttons {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

#display {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#clicked-buttons {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  display: block;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

#remove-button {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" id="1" value="1" >1</button>
    <button class="button" id="2" value="2" >2</button>
    <button class="button" id="3" value="3" >3</button>
    <button class="button" id="4" value="4" >4</button>
    <button class="button" id="5" value="5" >5</button>
    <button class="button" id="6" value="6" >6</button>
  </div>
  <img id="display" class="hidden">
  <button id="remove-button">Remove last input</button>
  <code id="clicked-buttons"></code>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain the naming scheme of the image files as well. What I mean to say is that how do you choose whether a file, like 'ABC123' and 'D9B6C4' exist but not 'BCA321'.

Comment: Hey, that's part of the problem: The naming convention is at random and is done through an additional piece of software that generates a 6-digit (or any other # of digit) names combining letters and numbers. That's essentially why sorting in any form won't help resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have any server-side tech that can scan the folder that contains the images?  Do you have a complete list of all the images? (implied by *parse through the pictures*)  To "try" every combo of 6 selected letters would 720 attempts, 7 => 5040 ... 12=> 479,001,600.   If you don't have an existing list then trying each one with an http request would be untenable.

Comment: Hey freedom, thanks for the heads up. I've fixed the tags. The website is hosted locally and is not supposed to be published. So no, there is no tech scanning the images. A complete list of images does exist however.

Comment: If you already have a list, then it's a case of matching a regex as `"[" + values.join('') + "]\.png"` or `regex = "(" + values.join('|') + "){" + values.length + "}"` your code limits up to 15 chars, so not clear if "ABC123" would match "A1.png" or if the filename must by the same length as the selected chars

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you explain in which part of the code that change would need to occur? And would I need to input the existing filenames somewhere in the code as well?

Comment: It would be just before your src= - have an array of existing values, loop through that array and regex compare each one until you find a match.  There's probably more efficient ways, but this should get you started.   If I can find time later and no-one else has by then, I'll put together some code, no time right now, sorry

Comment: much appreciated! It will probably take me a couple of days to figure out what exactly to do. If you find the time, I'd love for you to share a code. But already want to thank you very much!

Comment: Played around with the code a bit, trying to add a remove button, a display function as well as a log that tracks the clicked buttons. Unfortunately none of them is working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working solution, albeit its kind of hacky.

Have all of your images loaded in an array, just the file names.

Then loop through ALL of those files and create an object with the sorted name as the key and the file name as the value. That way no matter how the images are named, they will have a key like 999XXX.

Then it's just a matter of getting the buttons clicked and sorting its string until that string exists as a key.

```js
var imgs = ["ABC123.png", "1A2B4C.png"];

function case_insensitive_comp(strA, strB) {
  return strA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(strB.toLowerCase());
}

function reSortFiles() {
  var all = {};
  imgs.forEach(function(a) {
    d = a.split(".");
    img = d[0].split("");
    img = sortStr(img);
    img = img.join("");

    all[img] = a;
  });

  return all;
}

function sortStr(str) {
  return str.sort(case_insensitive_comp)
}

allImages = reSortFiles()

buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")

clicked = "";

buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    clicked += e.target.dataset.value;
    clicked = sortStr(clicked.split("")).join("")
    img = allImages[clicked]
    if (img) {
      console.log(img)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" data-value="A">A</button>
<button type="button" data-value="B">B</button>
<button type="button" data-value="C">C</button>
<button type="button" data-value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" data-value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" data-value="3">3</button>
```

---

Version that allows multiple

```js
var imgs = ["ABC123.png", "1A2B4C.png", "ABC132.png", "123ABC.png"];

function case_insensitive_comp(strA, strB) {
  return strA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(strB.toLowerCase());
}

function reSortFiles() {
  var all = {};
  imgs.forEach(function(a) {
    d = a.split(".");
    img = d[0].split("");
    img = sortStr(img);
    img = img.join("");

    all[img] ? all[img].push(a) : all[img] = [a];
  });

  return all;
}

function sortStr(str) {
  return str.sort(case_insensitive_comp)
}

allImages = reSortFiles()
console.log(allImages)


buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")

clicked = "";

buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    clicked += e.target.dataset.value;
    clicked_s = sortStr(clicked.split("")).join("")
    console.log(clicked, clicked_s)
    img = allImages[clicked_s]
    if (img) {
      console.log("Found: ", img.join(","))
      clicked=""; 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" data-value="A">A</button>
<button type="button" data-value="B">B</button>
<button type="button" data-value="C">C</button>
<button type="button" data-value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" data-value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" data-value="3">3</button>
<button type="button" data-value="4">4</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome work. I now have realised that I've made a mistake in formulating what the script should actually achieve and that I'll run into problems once the button values consist of more than 1 letter / 1 number. This would actually cause that some of my images in the folder would contain identical characters in different orders, e.g. AbAcAd413.png and AdAcAb413.png could both exist where this script would fail. Is there any possibility for the sorting to happen with e.g. AbAcAd staying in this order and not being split into seperate letters?

Comment: By generating a key-value pair up-front, this is substantially more efficient than a regex.  If can have multiple values with the same key (comment above) then you just need a small change of `all[img]=a` to `all[img] ? all[img].push(a) : all[img] = [a];` and the last console.log to `console.log(img.join(","))` / your final output to have multiple images.

Comment: awesome man! Is there any way to implement the console.log as a visible field like in the solution in my OP as well as have the image actually display instead of logging it? I've tried playing around and merging both codes but I seem to be stuck somewhere along the way.